# Docker Community App Fix renamed Mac OSX home directory

Tags: docker

Post installing Docker I changed the home directory on my Mac.

On start-up of Docker.app it still understandably tries to look at the old path.

[image]

How can I fix the containers path so it will start up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ooopps.

I just found this -

https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/troubleshoot/#troubleshooting

Docker for Mac does not start if Mac user account and home folder are renamed after installing the app
If, after installing Docker for Mac, you change the name of your macOS user account and home folder, Docker for Mac fails to start. To solve this problem, uninstall and reinstall Docker for Mac under the new user account.

Also - https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/faqs/#do-i-need-to-reinstall-docker-for-mac-if-i-change-the-name-of-my-macos-account

Comment: The docker uninstaller is not working for me though after renaming the home folder. And with https://stackoverflow.com/a/69437543 + reinstall I keep running into the problem that it wants to access the old path.

Answer (score 2):

Opening `~/Library/Group Containers/group.com.docker/settings.json` and editing the `dataFolder` value to include the new home directory's name fixed it for me.