# Unable to restart and remove Docker from Applications in Mac : Fatal Error failed to ping backend api

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

I suddenly got the `fatal error` message from Docker yesterday.  I really don't understand why as I shut down my machine properly.   So I decided to uninstall docker and reinstall it.  I went into the Applications folder in my Mac and I can't uninstall because it thinks the docker is open.  So I need help with the following:

1. how do I uninstall docker?
2. how do I install it so it can start working again?

Attempts at a resolution:

Just tried the following command in my terminal:

```
docker kill $(docker ps -q)
```

I got the following response:

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
"docker kill" requires at least 1 argument.
See 'docker kill --help'.
```

What do I do?

See the screen shot

[image]

Comment: Is this helping you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48813286/stop-all-docker-containers-at-once-on-windows

Comment: No.  these are for windows.  I am a Mac user.

Comment: Is running `docker kill $(docker ps -q)` in the CLI successfully stopping all Docker containers, allowing you to reinstall?

Comment: @LajosArpad  just updated my question.  With a response

Comment: Are there any containers running at this point?

Comment: There was one running yesterday.  but it was not being used.  I did update the container but did a proper shut down at the end of the day.

Comment: Is it running now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233610/discussion-between-fypnlp-and-lajos-arpad).

Comment: @LajosArpad  update. I was able to resolve the problem.  I detail how I fixed it

Comment: This helped me. https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/5037#issuecomment-780231914

Answer (score 34):

This was getting me crazy.

[image]

You don't need to reinstall Docker to solve it. The workaround (at least in my case) is as simple as killing all Docker related processes and running Docker again:

`$ pkill Docker`

`$ open -a /Applications/Docker.app`

Comment: Thank you killing the process did the magic for me

Answer (score 32):

1- open Activity monitor and go to com.docker. process , from there you have to kill it to proceed further.

2- uninstall from mac is standard procedure.

[image]

Comment: Got the following message from docker 'Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?'

Comment: @fypnlp did you slove that?

Comment: I ran Docker (Intel) on a Silicon Mac and that `com.docker.backend` service was still running, even after installing the correct version. Killing the process let the new copy run properly.

Answer (score 21):

In my case I was not able to use the Option of Rest and Diagnose too. UI was completely hung

Here's how I solved it.

1. Killed the docker process `$ pkill Docker`
2. Moved the docker application to bin
3. Manually deleted all the below files

   - `sudo rm -rf "/usr/local/lib/Docker"`
   - `sudo rm -rf "/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.docker.vmnetd"`
   - `sudo rm -rf "/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.docker.vmnetd.plist"`
   - `rm -rf "~/.docker"`
   - `rm -rf "~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker"`
   - `rm -rf "~/Library/Application Support/Docker Desktop"`
   - `rm -rf "~/Library/Preferences/com.docker.docker.plist"`
   - `rm -rf "~/Library/Saved Application State/com.electron.docker-frontend.savedState"`
   - `rm -rf "~/Library/Group Containers/group.com.docker"`
   - `rm -rf "~/Library/Logs/Docker Desktop"`
   - `rm -rf "~/Library/Preferences/com.electron.docker-frontend.plist"`
   - `rm -rf "~/Library/Cookies/com.docker.docker.binarycookies"`
4. Restarted the laptop
5. Installed the latest version again which worked fine

Comment: Aren't some of those "rm" commands incredibly dangerous, as written, and wrong?

For example:

rm -rf ~/Library/Application Support/Docker Desktop

Won't this in fact delete your Desktop folder? I think some surrounding quotes are missing, or the space between Application and Support needs to be escaped, as well as between Docker and Desktop?

Comment: The comment resolved m issuet BUUUUUUUUUUT;

Because of the Desktop removing at the end of the these commands, My entire Desktop content GOOOOONNNEEEE.

rm -rf ~/Library/Application Support/Docker Desktop, rm -rf ~/Library /Logs/Docker Desktop


PLEASE BE CAREFUL WITH IT!!!!!

Comment: re: 'Aren't some of those "rm" commands incredibly dangerous, as written, and wrong?' Yes, @NeerajMurarka, a good reminder to review before running commands from SO. I edited the post to add quotes.

Answer (score 14):

Ok, I was able to fix this problem.   You can do this with ANY application (just change the name), that you can't remove from the applications folder.

It will remove the entire application in its entirety.  The existence of the application is wiped clean.

Please do the following commands in this order

1. `ps aux  | grep docker`

When you run this command you get a big display.  You are only interested in the following thing in the his screen grab

[image]

2  Then do a `sudo kill` command that includes the number in the red box from the `ps aux|grep` command  as shown this code example in step 1.

```
sudo kill -9 108
```

3. Finally go to sudo remove command specifying the specific folder and application you want to remove.

   `sudo rm -rf /Applications/Docker.app/`
4. Restart your machine.
5. Install version of docker. If the error occurred when updating to a new version of docker (such as in my case).  You can [download an older version of docker from here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/release-notes/#docker-desktop-330) (the older version numbers are listed in the far left). I chose 3.3.0 (released 04/21 installed 6/11/21

Note:
If you have a problem installing an older version of docker and you encounter a problem
[image]

6. Run the following command and you will see a .json display

   `vi ~/Library/"Group Containers"/group.com.docker/settings.json`

Scroll down to settings and modify the version **down**.  For 3.3.0 I went down to  setting version 7.

7. Restart docker and when it opens check  images and you can see your containers

Answer (score 3):

It worked for me when I opened the terminal and then ran this:

```
killall Docker && cd /Applications;open -a Docker;cd ~
```

I found it here: https://www.lewuathe.com/how-to-deal-with-failed-to-ping-backend-api-in-docker.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing this error for docker version 3.6.0. then reinstall docker version 4.1.1  and it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this error, try installing the latest version of MacOS 13.4.1. I had the same problem with Docker and when I did this everything started to work again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).