# Auth error when pushing to Google Artifact Repository

Tags: gcloud, google-artifact-registry

I'm trying to push to GAR from my local machine, but I always get this error:

```
failed to authorize: failed to fetch anonymous token: unexpected status: 403 Forbidden
```

First, I've confirmed that my account has the Artifact Registry Writer role through IAM.

I have done the following locally:

```
# Login with my Google account
gcloud auth login --update-adc --force

# Configure docker to use the gcloud CLI auth helper
gcloud auth configure-docker us-west1-docker.pkg.dev

# docker login for good measure
docker login

# Tag my image (already built)
docker tag myimage us-west1-docker.pkg.dev/myproject/myrepo/myimage

# Push it
docker push us-west1-docker.pkg.dev/myproject/myrepo/myimage
```

On this final command I get the error above.

I have read all the Google documentation I could find but they all suggest the above steps:

- https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/pushing-and-pulling
- https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/troubleshoot

Note: I can't pull either, using the command provided directly from the GCP web UI.

I'm on M1 Mac.

Comment: For the first one, I have confirmed that the project name is correct. The ID and name are identical for this project. The latter uses a different auth flow, I want to get the user auth flow based working.

Comment: Does Docker's `config.json` `credHelpers` contain `"us-west1-docker.pkg.dev"`and `auths` section contain the key `https://us-west1-docker.pkg.dev/{project-id}/{repo}/{image}`? On Linux (!) I've had problems using non-standard Docker installs, it may be that the Mac has differences too. I'd try the `gcloud auth print-access-token | docker login --username=oauth2accesstoken --password-stdin https://us-west1-docker.pkg.dev/{project-id}/{repo}/{image}` flow to test without the helper.

Comment: It's unclear whether `myimage` is an `{image}:{tag}`. Although the commands should (!) default the tag (to `latest`), it's good practice to always include a tag. It's improbable but it *may* make a difference.

Comment: Hey, I have actually tested both cases, but yeah the tag in this case is `latest` since I leave it unspecified. As for the above things you recommend, I'll try those soon. I've now completely nuked my Docker installation, reset to factory defaults, and am trying my original steps again. Notably this time without the experimental containerd feature.

Answer (score 1):

So I was able to solve this problem by completely nuking Docker, specifically with these steps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69437543/3846032. I couldn't uninstall it by normal means, it would just hang, implying that the problems I was getting were a result of my Docker installation being very broken. Indeed, I managed to follow the above steps on another machine and it worked, which led me to conclude the steps above and my credentials were totally fine.

The 403 was a red herring, it must have come from my local Docker being broken in such a way that it doesn't send properly authenticated requests.