# Docker broken after renaming home directory

Tags: docker-desktop

I had to rename my user after setting up docker (and to rename the home directory as part of that).

This broke docker so that I get this error at startup:

[image: fatal error mkdir permission denied]

It says `getting disk info: checking sparse support: creating dir ...: mkdir <old home dir>: permission denied`.

I tried following [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69437543/2761682) to remove everything docker related and reinstall docker but it still fails.  *(Note: I noticed that some of the commands from that answer actually didn't run properly because they were not properly quoted, so, that might actually have worked.  I will not be trying this again, though.)*

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: this didn't quite fix it completely... just keeping the old dir there for now

---

I was able to resolve this with two changes:

One is I had to move the data directory:

```
{
  "builder": {
    "gc": {
      "defaultKeepStorage": "20GB",
      "enabled": true
    }
  },
  "data-root": "/Users/my-home-dir/.docker/data",
  "experimental": false,
  "features": {
    "buildkit": true
  }
}
```

Then docker desktop booted up fine.

After that docker client could not connect.  I saw that `/var/run/docker.sock` was symlinked to the old path.

So I fixed that:

```
sudo ln -sf $HOME/.docker/run/docker.sock /var/run/docker.sock
```

Comment: Unfort. I also had to rename my macOS username and after that I faced the same issue. This one was a solver for me https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/6201#issuecomment-1054071897

Comment: @yusuf Thank you for the link. You should propose this as an answer because it is the correct solution.